# HTML 5 FileSytem, combine FileEntry with MetaData array from callback

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

In a Chrome extension im using the HTML5 FileSytem API.

Im retrieving a list of records in a folder.

```
var entries = [];
var metadata = [];
listFiles(folder);

function listFiles(fs) {

    var dirReader = fs.createReader();
    entries = [];

    // Call the reader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.
    var readEntries = function () {
        dirReader.readEntries(function (results) {
            if (!results.length) {
                addMeta(entries);
            } else {
                console.log(results);
                entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
                readEntries();
            }
        });
    };

    readEntries(); // Start reading dirs.

}
```

The FileEntry object does not contain metadata, I need the last modified date. I'm able to retrieve a object of metadata

```
    function addMeta(entries) {
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        entries[i].getMetadata(function (metadata) {
            console.log(entries);
            console.log(metadata);
        });
    }
}
```

Problem is that i get the metadata in a callback.
How can i join the two object making sure the right match is made?
The simplified result im looking for is:

```
[
["fileName1", "modifyDate1"],
["fileName2", "modifyDate2"],
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get lastModifiedDate, you don't need to use `getMetadata`, as per the description of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688406/metadata-in-cordovas-file-api), just use `entry.file.lastModifiedDate`, though maybe `file()` is another callback.
2. To "join the two object making sure the right match is made", because of [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), you could use the following code to get the right results. (Assuming the data structure is `[[entry, metadata]]` as you mentioned)

   ```
   var ans = [];
   function addMeta(entries) {
       for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
           (function(entry) {
               entry.getMetadata(function (metadata) {
                   ans.push([entry, metadata]);
               });
           }(entries[i]);
       }
   }
   ```
3. If what you want is to wait for all asynchronous callback ends, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions) for more details, basically you could adjust your code and use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or use other implementations like `setInterval` or use a variable to calculate how many callbacks remain.

Comment: file also is a callback, but it contains both filename and modified date :), so no joining is needed! Thanks for elaborating on closures, i might need this concept soon!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look on Promise-based [bro-fs](https://github.com/vitalets/bro-fs) implementation of HTML Filesystem API.
To read all entries with metadata you can do something like this:

```
fs.readdir('dir')
  .then(entries => {
    const tasks = entries.map(entry => fs.stat(entry.fullPath))
    return Promise.all(tasks);
  })
  .then(results => console.log(results))
```